# C# draw in PictureBox "removes DPI scale"

Tags: c#, picturebox, dpi

I have a dialog box with a PictureBox. I am on a screen with 150% DPI scale...
When the dialog box displays on the screen... All is ok.
But as soon as I try assigning an image on the PictureBox, the dialog box scaling goes down to 100% and gets very small (for my screen).

I display the image on the PictureBox using:

```
pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = SharedResources.imageAsBitmap();
```

But I have also tried:

```
pictureBox1.Refresh();
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawImage(SharedResources.imageAsBitmap(), new Rectangle(0,0,pictureBox1.Width,pictureBox1.Height));
g.Dispose();
```

with no differences...

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Cyrille

Comment: `Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics()`_ Almost always a mistake. Make sure you know/control the dpi of the image. You can set it (`bmp.SetDpi(..)`)after loading and before using/drawing /assigning it..

Comment: Hello, I was not aware of this... But then why does my 2nd version, drawing on the picture box graphic not work either?

Comment: I may look right but it will not 'persist', ie it will disappear when you minimized etc the window.. You should use e.Graphics in the Paint event!